Why am I getting a low output voltage (5.98V instead of 12V) from a LM2623 stepup converter?
I'm working on a project using the LM2623 boost converter, where I aim to achieve a 12V output.
I'm only getting around 5.98V at the output. I've double-checked my circuit and measured the voltage at the FB (feedback) pin, which is approximately 598mV, much lower than the expected 1.24V.
Here are the key details of my setup:

R1 (top resistor of the voltage divider): 910 kΩ
R2 (bottom resistor of the voltage divider): 100 kΩ
Input voltage (V_BATT): 3.6 V
Inductor (L1): 4.7 µH
Capacitors (C1 and C2): 100 µF and 22 µF
Schottky Diode (D1): MBRS340T3G

Steps I’ve taken so far:

Checked resistor values (R1 and R2): They match the values as designed (910 kΩ and 100 kΩ).
Verified connections and solder joints: Everything seems fine.

What could be causing the low voltage at the FB pin and, consequently, the lower-than-expected output voltage? Is there something I might be missing?

Datasheet: link


How much load are you providing the output while measuring the voltage?

Also, have you tried other values for C14?  That can have a big impact.

Is this a two layer board? What does the grounding plane look like?

Note that the absolute maximum voltage allowed on the BOOT pin is 10 V per the datasheet.

The datasheet has this warning (emphasis added):

8.2.2.2 Choosing The Correct C3 Capacitor
The C3 capacitor allows for the duty cycle of the internal oscillator to be > programmable. Choosing
the correct C3 capacitor to get the appropriate duty cycle for a
particular application circuit is a trial and error process. The
nonlinear effect that C3 produces is dependent on the input voltage
and output voltage values. The correct C3 capacitor for particular
input and output voltage values cannot be calculated. Choosing the
correct C3 capacitance is best done by trial and error, in conjunction
with the checking of the inductor peak current to make sure your not
too close to the current limit of the device. As the C3 capacitor
value increases, so does the duty cycle. And conversely as the C3
capacitor value decreases, the duty cycle decreases. An incorrect
choice of the C3 capacitor can result in the part prematurely tripping
the current limit and/or double pulsing, which could lead to the
output voltage not being stable.

Frankly, between that (what the heck kind of design can't be calculated?- how repeatable is that?) and the BOOT pin voltage rating @John D mentioned in a comment, which has no particular recommendations offered in the datasheet or app notes, I would abandon this part and its relative, mentioned below.
TI forums show numerous issues with others trying to get 12V out from it, including a recommendation to switch to the LM2621. The LM2623 is supposed to support a D up to 0.9, and your requirement is for about 0.7 (LM2621 supports up to 0.8) but one response indicates this part (for digital cameras) was designed for a D\$\approx\$ 0.17!

+1, "Can't be calculated, use trial and error?" The main error is using this part in the first place....

I actually do not know what to take away from this.
I tried increasing C3 on the output.
I tried lowering RF1 and RF2.
I tried changing R3 to shift the operating frequency both up and down.
I tried adding the shortest possible jumper between pins 1 and 5.
The voltage never exceeded 5.9 V, even when I disconnected the load. After reconnecting, the load is about 400 mA, but the voltage remains the same.

@WITC It's possible your output went to 12 V or at least > 10 V for long enough to damage the part by blowing out the bootstrap circuit, so you may be dealing with a damaged part.

@JohnD I can replace it,  so hsould I Connect VDD and BOOT pin via rezistor divider? BOOT max = 10 V, and VDD max = 5 V?

Maybe tie BOOT to the input voltage (presumably your minimum will be 2.7 to 3V), but I don't see any guidance. Before swapping out the (quite possibly damaged) chip.

@Spehro Petfhany I replaced the circuit, connected BOOT + VDD to the input (3.6 V), and I get 12 V on the output when idle. However, under load (about 400 mA), it immediately drops to around 6.7 V.

That now sounds like a capacitor issue affecting the maximum D.

@SpehroPefhany so please dou you thing I should try to increase/decrease ouput capacitor?

Try varying C3.

@SpehroPefhany probably you think C14 in my design (which is equal to C3 in Datashhet typical application schematic) ?

Yes, try varying your C14.

When laying out the PCB for a DC DC converter, parasitics introduced by the PCB traces can be a problem because it changes the design. Therefore reducing parasitics from the traces and vias will help the design work as intended.
There needs to be more vias to ground. When you stick some via inductance between in between a ground or feedback loop, there can be problems.
You can find out if there are problems by seeing if there is a voltage difference on the grounds. You can do this by using a diff probe or two single ended probes and by probing the different grounding points. The voltage variation should be minimal. If you are getting above something like 50mVrms then there might be a problem.
Parallel vias so the AC currents have less AC 'resistance'. Make power traces wider to eliminate resistance and inductance.
